# TFS 2015 mapping issue like disabled local path

Tags: tfs-2015

I have a Team Foundation Server 2015 in a server machine and I am trying to connect my local machine, but I am unable to connect and get the source code facing an issue like mapping issue please help me to resolve this.

Comment: see [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already did all the steps what Shayki Abramczyk said, and still i cannot find the solution and finally i found whats the issue, the issues is i got two workspace name and both of that similarly mapping with the same path. finally i removed the unwanted workspace in my system then the issue solved. any how thanks for your input Mr.Shayki Abramczyk.

Comment: Ok, but the rule is "You can accept your own answer after 24 hrs". so will do that later. any how thanks for your information

Comment: @Yasin, Since this issue has been resolved, would you please mark your solution as the answer? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

In TFVC you need to map your local folder to the server:

- Open the Source Control Explorer
- Select the top node which should be your Server\Collection
- Right click and select Advanced | Map to Local Folder from the context menu
- Create a folder on the drive of your choice with the same name as the Collection. I like to create a Source folder then inside that folder create the Folder with the same name as the collection.  That way if I have more than one Collection they are separate folders but all under Source.

[image]

After the mapping, you can download the files from the TFS server.